# reload page in joomla but keep form data

Tags: javascript, php, session, joomla, get

I am developing a component in joomla 3 and it's my first time. This component is for desk reservation in a restaurant. I have a from which user should select a date and time to be able to see available desks.So after selecting the date and time I have used a button(seeavail) to show available desks.
My problem is that I don't know how to keep entered data in the form and reload the page.
First I tried to use javascript as below, but beforeunload event doesn't happen.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   jQuery("#seeavail").click(function(){
        location.reload();
  });
  
   jQuery(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
        localStorage.setItem("name",  jQuery('#customername').text());
  alert( "beforeonload");
  }); 
 jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
        var name = localStorage.getItem("name");
  if (name !== null) jQuery('#customername').text("abs");
  alert( "load");
    }); 
    });
```

Then I thought I should use Joomla $session->set and get ,as I searched more or maybe get method. Right now I am confused and any help in simple words and samples is appropriated.

Comment: I would use the built in API for this. You might want to review Joomla documentation or ask for help on the Joomla stack exchange site [joomla.se]